# Can we have MS Sql Server as data source for Druid for data loading?

Tags: sql-server, olap-cube, druid

Can we have MS Sql Server as data source for Druid for data loading. If not what is the best possible way for data ingestion to Druid from MS SQL Server?

We actually need to create **data cubes** using Druid currently our database is MS SQL server. What could be best possible way to load data to **Druid** from **Microsoft Sql Server**?

Comment: https://cleanprogrammer.net/how-to-configure-druid-to-use-microsoft-sql-server-as-metadata-storage/